# react native access content:// uri fails

Tags: android, react-native

Working with the following react native packages in android:

```
"react-native": "0.47.2"
"react-native-document-picker": "2.0.0" (removing the ovveride to compile with 0.47)
"react-native-fetch-blob": "^0.10.8"
```

I'm getting a content:// uri while using react-native-document-picker or react-native-contacts (for the avatars).
URIs like:

```
 'content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A99'
```

Trying to access this file fails with "stat error: failed to list path null for it is not exist or it is not a folder'"

```
const urlDecoded = decodeURIComponent(url);
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  RNFetchBlob.fs.stat(urlDecoded)
    .then(resolve)
    .catch(reject);
});
```

Any idea how to access the file? access the real path of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a solution for this problem in react-native-fs. Enabling access and copy content:// files -https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/pull/395

Comment: I'm having the same problem, even though I'm using the `react-native-fs`, what did you mean by your answer ? can you explain more please ?

Comment: Can you put that solution in the answer here!

Answer (score 0):

check your **AndroidManifest.xml** and write `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and double-check that those permissions are granted.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with accessing media(content uri) files from an external app like music etc. No need to add anything just follow my answer.

I have fixed it by adding PermissionsAndroid from react-native

here is the code:

`"react-native": "0.64.2"`

`"react-native-document-picker": "^7.1.3",`

```
import {PermissionsAndroid, ToastAndroid} from 'react-native';

const uploadAudio = async finalSubmit => {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      {
        title: 'Storage Permission',
        message: 'App needs access to memory to upload the file ',
      },
    );
    if (granted != PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      ToastAndroid.showWithGravity(
        'You need to give storage permission to upload the file',
        ToastAndroid.SHORT,
        ToastAndroid.BOTTOM,
      );
      return false;
    }
  };
  uploadAudio();
```

I hope this helps you :)